# Replacing innertext of XML node using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml

I want to replace innertext of a XML node my XML file named `test.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads>
    <loop>no</loop>
    <item>
        <description>Description 1</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Text in item2</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Let play with this XML</description>
    </item>
</ads>
```

I want to change the value of `loop` and `description` tag both,
and it should be saved in `test.xml` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads>
    <loop>yes</loop>
    <item>
        <description>Description Changing Here</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Changing text in item2</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>We will play later</description>
    </item>
</ads>
```

I tried code in PHP:

```
<?
    $file = "test.xml";
    $fp = fopen($file, "rb") or die("cannot open file");
    $str = fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadXML($str) or die("Error");
    //$dom->load("items.xml");

    $root=$dom->documentElement; // This can differ (I am not sure, it can be only documentElement or documentElement->firstChild or only firstChild)

    $loop=$root->getElementsByTagName('loop')->item(0);//->textContent;
    //echo $loop;
    if(trim($loop->textContent)=='no')
    {
        echo 'ok';
        $root->getElementsByTagName('loop')->item(0)->nodeValue ='yes';
    }
    echo "<xmp>NEW:\n". $dom->saveXML() ."</xmp>";
?>
```

I tried only for `loop` tag.I don't know how to replace `nodevalue` in `description tag`.
When I run this page it shows output like:

```
ok
NEW:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads>
    <loop>yes</loop>
    <item>
        <description>Description 1</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Changing text in item2</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <description>Let play with this XML</description>
    </item>
</ads>
```

It gives the value `yes` in browser but don't save it in `test.xml` any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, since you have created `DOMDocument` you can use [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). Or keep using `getElementsByTagName()`

You could do this (but only in that context):

```
$descriptions = $root->getElementsByTagName('description');
foreach($descriptions as $nodeDesciption)
{
    $nodeDesciption->nodeValue ='Your custom value';
}
```

Comment: This code will update same text in each and every description tag but I don't want this, I want different values in each description tag as shown in my output.

Comment: @RohanKumar obviously you need to add your own logic into `foreach` block. You have access to node (that also includes access to attributes, siblings, parents etc) so you can modify it in the way you need it to be modified.